# Marshal (or Convert) a Object instance to Map in GAE (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have this code that worked with GAE Unit test, however when run in a GAE App environment its throwing reflection error:

```
public Map<String,Object> createMapFrom(Object instance){
    Map<String,Object> result = org.boon.Maps.toMap(instance);
    return result;
}
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.boon.core.reflection.Reflection
```

Question is, what is the available way to marshal a object instance into a Map in the GAE environment?

Comment: could you elaborate a bit in what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Make a Map out of a Object instance that will work with GAE

Comment: and this is failing on the cloud and working on your local environment?

Comment: Not working even in local. It is calling Reflection

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox):

> An application is allowed full, unrestricted, reflective access to its
>   own classes.
>
> It may query any private members, call the method
>   java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(), and read/set
>   private members.
>
> An application can also reflect on JRE and API classes, such as
>   java.lang.String and javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest. However,
>   it can only access public members of these classes, not protected or
>   private.
>
> An application cannot reflect against any other classes not belonging
>   to itself, and it can not use the setAccessible() method to circumvent
>   these restrictions.

My best guess is Boon is tapping into some forbidden Reflection feature in GAE. A quick search turned out this post, where people on the project acknowledge the issue and looking for a solution.